# How to transfer variables from a scope to another in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

```
// Somewhere in FooCtrl

$scope.myvar = 'titi'
    $location.path('/viewSubscribe'); // redirection to the subscribe page
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the "myvar" variable in the $scope of SubscribeCtrl (linked to /viewSubscribe route).

What is the clean way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are several ways, depending on the use case. Here are some approaches ordered by level of relevancy to yours:

## Route it <sup><sub><sup>[(demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/oEyMmhBlOaJN9fcSAhHx?p=preview)</sup></sub></sup>

#### To the path

Pass it as a path variable, and define the variable name in when routing (in the `$routeProvider` configuration):

```js
// somewhere
$scope.myvar = 'titi';
$location.path('/viewSubscribe/' + $scope.myvar);
// ...

// in the module configuration    
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/viewSubscribe/:myVar', {
            templateUrl: 'views/myView.html',
            controller: 'MyCtrl'
        })
    // etc.
});
```

Then you can inject the route parameters service to the desired location, and get the path variable's value:

```js
// somewhere else    
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($routeParams, $log) {
    $log.info($routeParams['myVar']); // --> 'titi'
});
```

## Shoot it <sup><sub><sup>[(demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPtmvtQwyxqfU1VGCb4W)</sup></sub></sup>

#### As in *"event fired"*

You can fire events to scopes up or down the hierarchy with the scope's `$emit()` or `$broadcast()`, respectively, e.g.:

```js
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('model.text', function(newVal) {
        $scope.$broadcast('myVarChanged', newVal);
    });
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$on('myVarChanged', function (myVar) {
        $log.info(myVar); // --> 'titi'
    });
});
```

## Fix it <sup><sub><sup>[(demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/3GbkHAz6xVQa5JXD27Ve)</sup></sub></sup>

#### As in *"for good"*

You can also set it once, and get it everywhere, if you declare it as a constant (or a value):

```js
// at some outer level
app.constant('myVar', 'titi');
```

```js
// anywhere, really
app.controller('MyCtrl', function(myVar, $log) {
    $log.info(myVar); // --> 'titi'
});
```

## Plant it <sup><sub><sup>[(demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/PC6XZXQDUBvlTX1Xmzdy)</sup></sub></sup>

#### So it has *roots*

Declare it in the root scope, so it is shared to all scopes:

```js
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.myVar = 'titi';
});

// later
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope, $log) {
    $log.info($rootScope.myVar); // --> 'titi'
    $log.info($scope.myVar); // --> 'titi'
});
```

This method is less recommended, as it sets a common property for all inherited scopes, which can be easily overridden or shadowed (scopes are inherited prototypaly) and it cannot be used with isolated scopes (i.e. in directives that define their scope as such).

Comment: Thanks. Does it work when `myvar` is a complex object like an array of another objects?

Comment: see the updated answer. it will work with objects if you set them as constants / values, but you can only pass strings values on the path. btw the way to say thank you around here, is to upvote the answer :)

Comment: as i said, upvoting is the way to say *thank you*. if it solved you issue, you can accept it, regardless :)

Comment: Hey, I was told this is a very bad practice to transfer variable from a controler no another one. If I want to share data between them, I should make them use a common service. What do you think about that? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidW., that depends on the case. generally speaking, services are meant for representing units of control, mostly stateful objects. as you asked about a "variable", i didn't offer them in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you don't want to retrieve the variable as a path parameter you can also make use of services. These are guaranteed to last for the duration of an AngularJS app.
See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

You can then store the variables inside your service as you would from a normal Java-like class and pass the services via dependency injection.